# Pandas rename columns with wildcard

Tags: pandas, rename, wildcard

My df looks like this:

```
Datum   Zeit    Temperatur[Â°C]     Luftdruck   Windgeschwindigkeit[m/s]    Windrichtung[Grad]  Relative Luftfeuchtigkeit[%]    Globalstrahlung[W/mÂ²]
```

Now i want to rename the columns like this:#

```
wetterdaten.rename(columns={'Temperatur%': 'Temperatur', 'Luftdruck[hPa]': 'Luftdruck'}, inplace=True)
```

Where `%` is a wildcard.
But of course it will not work like this.

The beginning of the column name is always the same in the log data,
but the ending is temporally changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the columns and fetch the name:

```
wetterdaten.rename(columns={wetterdaten.filter(regex='Temperatur.*').columns[0]: 'Temperatur', 
                            wetterdaten.filter(regex='Luftdruck.*').columns[0]: 'Luftdruck'},
                   inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict`, for wildcard use `.*` and for start of string `^`:

```
d = {'^Temperatur.*': 'Temperatur', 'Luftdruck[hPa]': 'Luftdruck'}
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(d, regex=True)
```

Sample:

```
cols = ['Datum',   'Zeit',    'Temperatur[Â°C]', 'Luftdruck' ,  'Windgeschwindigkeit[m/s]',
        'Windrichtung[Grad]',  'Relative Luftfeuchtigkeit[%]',   ' Globalstrahlung[W/mÂ²]']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Datum, Zeit, Temperatur[Â°C], Luftdruck, Windgeschwindigkeit[m/s], 
          Windrichtung[Grad], Relative Luftfeuchtigkeit[%],  Globalstrahlung[W/mÂ²]]
Index: []

d = {'^Temperatur.*': 'Temperatur', 'Luftdruck.*': 'Luftdruck'}
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Datum, Zeit, Temperatur, Luftdruck, Windgeschwindigkeit[m/s], 
          Windrichtung[Grad], Relative Luftfeuchtigkeit[%],  Globalstrahlung[W/mÂ²]]
Index: []
```

Comment: That is not what i want.

Comment: @kolja could you explain why this is not the result that you want? Because it looks to me this is exactly the result you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You may prepare a function for renaming you columns:

```
rename_columns(old_name):
    if old_name == 'Temperatur':
        new_name = old_name + whichever_you_wants    # may be another function call
    elif old_name == 'Luftdruck':
        new_name = 'Luftdruck[hPa]'
    else:
        new_name = old_name
    return new_name
```

and then use the `.rename()` method with that function as a parameter:

```
wetterdaten.rename(columns=rename_columns, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This might not be exactly what OP needed, but it is exactly what I need. And it is by far the cleanest solution. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try the below code; Which replaces `#Item Code` into `Item Name` without condition.

Code:

```
pd.rename(columns = {'#Item Code':'Item Name'}, inplace = True)
```