# How to combine many python dataframes to a single dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have over 1500 python dataframes that I need to combine to one large dataframe. The issue that I have is that dataframes have unique column headers and different sizes.

For example dataframe 1 is:

```
type    sc98*c.firstname    sc98*c.lastname    sc98*c.username    text                  createdAt    statusofExpiration
need    John                Doe                johndoe            I need a new car.     111111       expired
```

And dataframe 2 is:

```
type    l8!7s4fn.firstname    l8!7s4fn.lastname    l8!7s4fn.username    text                    tags.0    tags.1    image.0        createdAt    statusOfExpiration
need    Matt                  Smith                mattsmith            I need a yoga trainer.  yoga      trainer   blankurl.com/  22222        fulfilled
```

And I want to end up with a data frame like:

```
type    firstname    lastname    username    text                    createdAt    statusofExpiration    tags.0    tags.1    image.0
need    John         Doe         johndoe     I need a new car.       111111       expired       
need    Matt         Smith       mattsmith   I need a yoga trainer.  222222       fulfilled             yoga      trainer   blankurl.com/
```

As I mentioned, I won't be able to call the values by indices because of the variable dataframes sizes and I can't call the values by the column name because dataframes have a unique identifiers (e.g. id.username) in the column headers.

Is there anyway to get around this problem?

Comment: Don't post dataframes as images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115262/merge-multiple-dataframe-pandas)

Comment: It's a bit more than (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115262/merge-multiple-dataframe-pandas) as the names of the column are not exactly the same, look at the one with firstname. Need a `rename` on column first

Comment: @Ben.T I can't view the images unfortunately so without that further information it looked like a dupe to me :/ I think the question would be made a lot better with the images either embedded or formatted into the text body

Comment: I am sorry about the images, I tried writing down the dataframes but they were showing in multiple rows. Gutted that there is no Table functionality in stackoverflow.

Comment: @RBalasubramanian make sense, and I agree with you about the picture ;)

Comment: @Turtle Maybe try to use the code formatting (symbol is `{ }` when you write a question it's just above the text area) to make the lines of your data looks better.

Comment: @Ben.T thank you. I just fixed it!

Comment: @Turtle are the columns always ordered with `type` then `firstname`, then `lastname`, then `username`, then other columns even if the name of the column is not exactly `firstname` for example?

Comment: @Ben.T no, some dataframes have additional columns between type and the first name

Comment: Ideally, I would like to rename the columns for each dataframe, however I can't extract the exact names or indices of the these columns. Solving this problem would be helpful if there is a contain method within pandas so that column names such as "sc98*c.firstname" which contain "firstname" are renamed to "firstname".

Answer (score 0):

Since the data frames have unique column headers and different sizes there is not a simple way to concatenate the data frames. I would reccomend looking into the following:

```
df.filter(like='firstname')  # select columns containing the word firstname
```

This way you can loop through the column names in all of the data frames and rename them based on partial matches.

Look into this post: [Pandas rename colums with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706850/pandas-rename-colums-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to concatenate or merge multiple data frames. Hope this help !

```
df1 = DataFrame(
{
    'First Name': firstname_list,
    'Last Name': lastname_list,
 }
)

df2 = DataFrame(
{
    'Key1': value_list1,
    'Key2': value_list2,
 }
)

frames = [df1, df2]

concatenated_df = pd.concat(frames)
concatenated_df.to_csv(r'dataset.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```